# Will silicon dioxide react with hydrochloric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, reactivity

I have the following equation, based on the reaction of $\ce{SiO2}$ with $\ce{HF}:$

$$\ce{SiO2 + HCl -> SiCl4 + 2 H2O}$$

I want to know if this reaction is indeed feasible, what conditions may be needed to induce it, or if it isn't possible why that's the case.

Comment: No, HCl does not etch SiO2 appreciably.

Comment: @JonCuster You say 'appreciably', what do you mean by that?

Comment: You can store HCl in a glass bottle. Please don't do that with HF.

Comment: Well, Cl is very much **not** like F. For this reason, the reaction is totally impossible. Or rather, it will go quite readily, only _backwards_.

Comment: @IvanNeretin What is it about `Cl` that makes it unsuitable compared to `F`? Is it simply proton count or something more?

Comment: @JonCuster Rest assured I'm well aware of the risks of dealing with `HF`, I'm trying to develop a process that avoids it.

Comment: @faissaloo - in grad school somebody really messed up a hood by being lazy and pouring HF waste into the (glass) waste bottle sitting there (for aluminum etchant). What a mess to clean up!

Comment: Well, they are different chemical elements; isn't that enough of a justification for _any_ of their properties to be different? In particular, size matters. F is small, which makes the formation of $\ce{SiF6^2-}$ possible and even desirable. Not so with Cl.

Comment: HCl reacts with oxides of Ge, Sn and Pb but not Si. See this answer: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/60757/which-hydrogen-halides-react-with-group-14-oxides?r=SearchResults

Comment: The combination of both those comments answers my question.

Comment: The reaction works with a high efficiency in the opposite sense : $\ce{SiCl_4}$ reacts quite easily with the slightest amount of water to produce huge fumes of silica + HCl. This reaction has been used in war times for hiding tanks advancing in the direction of the enemy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the paper by Chung and Sturm [[1](https://doi.org/10.1149/1.2727426)], $\ce{HCl}$ will do a very small amount of etching at high enough temperatures (525 °C will give you about 1 nm/min), but the presence of hydrogen limits the reaction because the formation of $\ce{HCl}$ is preferred to the formation of $\ce{SiCl4}.$

#### References

1. Chung, K. H.; Sturm, J. C. Chlorine Etching for In-Situ Low-Temperature Silicon Surface Cleaning for Epitaxy Applications. In *ECS Transactions*; ECS: Chicago, Illinois, **2007**; Vol. 6, pp 401–407. DOI: [10.1149/1.2727426](https://doi.org/10.1149/1.2727426).